# UIResponder touch points vs UIGestureRecognizer touch points

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uiresponder

I wanted to know what the differences between the points available from `UIResponder` methods from `UITouch` object and points available from `UIGestureRecognizer` object. I'm sure we will not get all the points on the device when a finger is moved. Is it the same number of points say for a pan is available for both the API or if any API gives more points? Which is better to track all the touched points?